# Difference between "a" and "any": “Can a/any bulletproof vest stop a bullet...?”

Tags: indefinite-article, determiners

What is the difference between **a** and **any** in the following sentence?

- Can **a** bulletproof vest stop a bullet fired from an AK-47?
- Can **any** bulletproof vest stop a bullet fired from an AK-47?

Does the second one using **any** mean to say "Does there exist **a single** bulletproof vest that can stop a bullet fired from an Ak-47"?

Answer (score 1):

In this context, both 'a' and 'any' mean more or less the same. However,

> Can a bulletproof vest stop a bullet fired from an AK-47?

This means -

```
Is every bulletproof vest capable of stopping a bullet fired from an AK-47?
```

> Can any bulletproof vest stop a bullet fired from an AK-47?

This means -

```
Is there even one bulletproof vest capable of stopping a bullet from an AK-47?
```